# How can I have customers log in using ONLY customer number? No password

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I am needing to allow users to log in using nothing but a single number that is provided to them(their subscriber number). No password. Our current .NET website is set up this way, but we may switch to Wordpress.

I do realize the security implications and other factors, etc. I just need them to be able to access a page of subscriber-only content. They don't need access to the admin or anything else. They just need to be able to put in a single number and get access.

Thanks!

Comment: can't the subscriber number considered as password? Is there user name associated with the subscriber number or is it just the number?

Comment: The number can be either username or password(we'll have a system that automatically assigns their number after subscribing, so it would have to be something we assign, as they wont' be signing up on the site themselves). So there CAN be a username associated, but we don't need or want them to worry about it. They should only need their subscriber number to login. As far as the user knows, they will be unaware of anything but that number. 

If I can't tweak core to get this to work, I'm open to other plugin or membership solutions that may be available, including commercial ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hack a little bit to achieve this. First of all, don't touch Wordpress default login. That can mess things up a lot.

I think for your case, it would be best to create a secondary login system. For this, you would need to store the customer numbers in a separate table.(It's not apparent from your question how sensitive this customer number is, how they are generated and their effect in contrast to the password. So store them appropriately.)

Create a page template for the login page.(I'm assuming the customer number is added by admin, in which case you need to create a admin page in the backend to add/edit/delete customer number)

Now you need to store the login details in a session. But Wordpress doesn't allow session. You can activate PHP Session or use this plugin instead: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/

Now on the page where you want to restrict access, you can check whether user is logged in and show the content or send them to the secondary login page.

If this is needed only a single page, you might not need session at all. When user visit the page, show them a form to submit their customer number and on form post do the validation. This will require user to input their customer number in every page load.